# string.search() function cannot parse string from XML response

Tags: javascript, xml, netsuite

I'm using someresponse.getBody(); to store the XML response I'm getting back from a webservice. When I pass this to the below function, it's not able to be parsed corrected using search() or indexOf(). Both return a start and end pos of 10 and -1.

However, when I pulled the body of the response from the execution logs and hard coded the variable with that value. When I pass that value to the same function, it is processed as I expect.

This looks to be a format issue. Any idea what I can do here?
I'm restricted to just using Javascript or NetSuite API's and the code runs server side.

I call the function using: var xmlCCConnote = getValue('CCConnote', response);

```
function getValue(tag,xmlString){
    var value;  
    var tempString;  
    var startTag,endTag;  
    var startPos,endPos;  
    startTag = "<"+tag+">";  
    endTag = "</"+tag+">";  
    tempString=xmlString;
    startPos = tempString.indexOf(startTag) + startTag.length;
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'startPos = ', startPos);
    endPos = tempString.indexOf(endTag);
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'endPos = ', endPos);
    value = tempString.slice(startPos,endPos);  
    return value;  
}
```

Comment: Is there no proper XML parser available?  Using string manipulation to parse values out of XML is very error prone, as you have found out.  There could be an issue with encoding or escaping the output.  I would try to get a hex dump of your input string to make sure that there's nothing funny going on.

Comment: We do have API's for parsing XML using XPATH, but I'm still waiting for NetSuite to respond to my questions there as they return no value. This is just supposed to be a temporary solution until the XML API's are setup correctly.

Comment: And you can't use 3rd party libraries? Yikes.  At this point all that I can recommend is to find a stand-alone case that replicates the issue, and then post it here.  If you say that it works when the XML is hardcoded and not when run, then *something* is different with the input, and I would figure that out before attempting to modify your extraction function.

Comment: We can use third party libraries.
I assume by this you mean we can add other JS files to the script setup and call those functions.
We already do that with some of CryptoJS.

Comment: Are you bound to Restlet ? You can use SuiteTalk instead.

Comment: I figured out the problem today when I was attempting to use slice method to extract the value I need. I noticed while using slice that I was seeing escape codes in the output. So I determined that the XML string I was searching contained escape codes even though I was not seeing them in the Execution Log output.

Essentially the fix was this:
startTag = '&lt;'+tag+'&gt;';
endTag = '&lt;/'+tag+'&gt;';

Hope this helps if anyone has a similar issue with the getValue function.

Answer (score 0):

The xmlstring I was passing into the function was escaped. The following fixed the issue:

```
startTag = '&lt;'+tag+'&gt;';
endTag = '&lt;/'+tag+'&gt;';
```